# Java Reflection on an Integer Object

Tags: java, reflection

Given the following Java code:

```
int     x[] = new int[3];
Integer y[] = new Integer[3];

java.lang.reflect.Array.setInt(x, 0, 10);   // works as expected (i.e. x[0] = 
10)
java.lang.reflect.Array.setInt(x, 1, 20);   // works as expected (i.e. x[1] = 20)
java.lang.reflect.Array.setInt(x, 2, 30);   // works as expected (i.e. x[2] = 30)

java.lang.reflect.Array.setInt(y, 0, 10);   // throws an exception

java.lang.reflect.Array.setInt(y, 1, 20);   // throws an exception

java.lang.reflect.Array.setInt(y, 2, 30);   // throws an exception
```

Why can one use reflection to assign values to variable `x`, while it is not possible to do so for variable `y`?

Comment: Because `y` is an `Integer[]`, and `x` is an `int[]`.

Comment: That method throws an exception "If the specified object argument is not an array, or if the specified value cannot be converted to the underlying array's component type by an **identity or a primitive widening conversion**".  It doesn't handle boxing for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that to make it work with `y`, you will need to write

```
 java.lang.reflect.Array.set(y, 0, Integer.valueOf(10));
```

as reflection won't take care of boxing for you.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
public class ArrayReflectionTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer[] y = new Integer[3];
      java.lang.reflect.Array.set( y, 0, 10 );
      System.out.println( y[0] );
   }

}
```

Since `10` will be auto-boxed to an `Integer`, you don't have to explicitly convert it.  However if your array is any type besides `Integer`, I think you will have to explicitly convert it (to `Byte`, `Character`, `Long`, etc.).  I don't think object types will be converted in those cases.